# Rails belongs_to association with multiple foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to figure out a way to define a `belongs_to` association where the target record can be found by one of 4 different columns. The setup:

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :managerships, foreign_key: :employee_id
  has_many :managers, through: :managerships
end
```

**Managership**

```
class Managership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :manager # <-- ideas?
end
```

The `managerships` table has  4 columns `manager_id`, `manager_custom_id`, `manager_email`, `manager_saml_id` that we can use to look up the user's managers. For every `Managership`, only one of these columns is ever present.

I'm looking for a way to be able to call `user.managers` (a manager is a `User`) so that it returns all users where `managerships.manager_id = users.id OR managerships.manager_custom_id = users.custom_id OR managerships.manager_email = users.email OR managerships.manager_saml_id = users.saml_id`

Many thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Although, I would doubt that 4 foreign keys for one relation is a good idea at all, one way to get managers from User is to use method instead of scope. However you won't be able to use `#joins`, if you do so.

```
class User
  def managers
   self.class.joins(:managerships).where('managerships.manager_id = ? OR managerships.manager_custom_id = ? OR managerships.manager_email = ? OR managerships.manager_saml_id', id, custom_id, emd, saml_id)
  end
end
```

in `Managership` you can do similar thing, declare `#manger` instead of `belongs_to :manager`

Comment: Thank you, Nikita. While this may be the way to go, it does not return managers. `self.class.joins(:managerships)` will return all users who have a manager (see `has_many :managerships, foreign_key: :employee_id`), not managers themselves

Comment: @JanKlimo Yeah right. Let me think it over the sql, it's not gonna be an easy one :/